# How to prove $ E - ( A \cap B ) $ = $ (E- A) \cup (E - B) $ where for the purpose of this exercise E is a set that all other sets are a subset of.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I understand what the left hand side is stating. The set of elements containing E (where E is a set that all other sets are a subset of for the purpose of this exercise ) but excluding elements in both A and B. However, I don't understand how you can get the right hand side from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction is obvious: as $A\cap B\subset A, B$, the complements $E\setminus A$ and $E\setminus B$ are contained in $A\setminus A\cap B $, hence their union.

Conversely, consider an element of $E$ which is not in $A\cap B$. This means it cannot  belong to both of them. So, either it does not belong to $A$ (but possibly to $B$), in which cas it belongs to $E\setminus A$ by definition, hence to $(E\setminus A)\cup(E\setminus B).$ Similar argument if the element does not belong to $B$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x \in E \setminus (A \cap B)= \\ =x \in E \land x \notin (A \cap B) =\\ = x \in E \land (x \notin A \lor x \notin B)= \\=
(x \in E \land x \notin A) \lor (x \in E \land x \notin b) =\\= x \in (E \setminus A ) \cup (E \setminus B )$$

Comment: The equal signs don't make sense. Maybe you meant $\iff$?

Comment: @celtschk. Equal sign here make sense - look please at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equality - It means equality between sentences with logical values i.e. for all values of variables included in the expression, the values of sentences are equal. Here I feel that the use of $\iff$ (btw I prefer $\Leftrightarrow$) everywhere overloads the expression and loses individual fragments that I would like to emphasize.

Comment: But as is, your formula claims that e.g. $E\setminus(A\cap B)=x$. At least you need to set parentheses if you want to use $=$ that way. And I certainly can't see what you want to emphasize here.

Comment: Now I understand how you see it:  sign "$=$" is used as delimiter also. In expression you brought "$\in$" have more priority, then "$=$" so you cannot split $x$ from its right "$\in$".  I work with many sources, with similar notations, but, as I see now, there are some people for whom it is not so. I divide expressions to different lines - is it more understandable now?

Comment: Yes, the separate lines help a lot. Now I can visually follow the proof, and it makes clear how you mean it. Also, the different expressions are now sufficiently visually separated to not take too much effort to check. I now can see that your derivation is correct, and indeed is the best of the answers here.

Comment: My fault is that I could not imagine, that this was incomprehensible to anyone, and by the way, I was very surprised at the existing reaction. Chatting with you definitely made a better record - thank you for it and also for rating.

Answer (score 0):

$X-Y$ is equivalent to $X\cap Y'$.
So, $$E-(A\cap B)=E\cap (A\cap B)'\\=E\cap (A'\cup B')=(E\cap A')\cup (E\cap B')\\=(E- A)\cup (E- B)$$

Comment: In your second step, you are using the very relation to be proved.